# Dubbio su questa frase?

Tags: grammar

> "Per essere indossata non c'è bisogno di far passare la testa attraverso il buco"
>
> "Per indossarla non c'è bisogno di far passare la testa attraverso il buco"

Ora, sono sicuro che la seconda frase è corretta, mentre la prima invece mi sembra scorretta, ma non saprei dire perché.

Sapreste dirmi se la mia impressione è giusta, e per quale ragione?

Comment: Quali dubbi hai sulla prima frase?

Comment: Nella prima frase è la testa che dev'essere indossata?

Comment: @DaG - stesso dubbio per la seconda. Soggetto sottinteso per entrambe in realtà.

Comment: Si parla di una maglietta

Comment: @Nakamura Al momento la domanda è molto poco chiara. Potresti spiegare meglio quali sono questi dubbi?

Comment: La prima frase non mi sembra corretta., mi riferisco alla parte" per essere indossata". Continuo a ripetermela ma mi suona corretta solo la seconda. Il senso delle due frasi è: se voglio indossarla non devo far passare la testa attraverso il buco, poiché non è necessario.

Comment: @Nakamura Ho provato a includere il commento precedente nella domanda. Sentiti libero di cambiarla se ho frainteso

Comment: @Denis Nardin: volevo sapere se " per essere indossata" potesse sostituirsi a "per indossarla" vicino a "non c'è bisogno di" e se c'è differenza di significato.

Comment: Se per il contesto è chiaro che si sta parlando di una maglietta, sono corrette entrambe. La prima è però più articolata, sia nella grammatica che nella pronuncia: ecco il motivo per cui ti sembra più "scorretta".